# How to get inherited parametrized field class by reflections?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

```
class A extends B<C> {
   ...
}

class B<T extends E> {
   ...
   public D<T> field;
}
```

**How can I get class "C" from "field" reflections?**

Now I just can get class "B" fields as "A" superclass fields and looks like they don't know which type parameter is passed from "A" and shows only type "E".

Comment: Have a look at type erasure, what you try to achieve will just not work due to the limitations of java generics

Comment: could you give an example of what you try to retrieve ? Sorry it is not very clear.

Comment: @davidxxx what class have "field", in class "A" before any new instance will be created

Comment: How class `C` is related to that field? as you can't do that by using only field alone, as field is not related to that `A` class. Also, can you describe why you need this? sounds interesting.

Comment: @GotoFinal C is parameter to field type. It uses for code generating.

Comment: C is not a parameter of field type. this field does not know about C or even A

Comment: @GotoFinal A set C as parameter to B, C becomes T in B, T is parameter in D type of field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `A` extends `B` with a concrete type `C`, that does not change the type of the field in `B` that you get from reflection.

You can however manually map from the field's type variable to the concrete type. You first build a map of `TypeVariable`s to concrete types for the `A` class, and then you use that to translate the type variables in `B` into concrete types.

```
Class<?> cls = A.class; // using `A` as an example
Class<?> sup = cls.getSuperclass();

 // TypeVariables of `B`
TypeVariable<?>[] tv = sup.getTypeParameters();
 // Concrete types used to extend with in `A`
Type[] actual = ((ParameterizedType) cls.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();

Map<TypeVariable<?>, Type> mappings // map one to the other
    = IntStream.range(0, tv.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> tv[i], i -> actual[i]));


for(Field f : sup.getDeclaredFields()) {
    Type t1 = f.getGenericType();
    System.out.println(t1); // prints `D<T>`
    Type t2 = concretify(t1, mappings);
    System.out.println(t2); // prints `D<C>`
}
```

```
public static Type concretify(Type from, Map<TypeVariable<?>, Type> mappings) {
    if(from instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) from;

        Type[] ts = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
        Type[] result = new Type[ts.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {
            result[i] = mappings.getOrDefault(ts[i], ts[i]);
        }

        return new ParameterizedType() { // some ParameterizedType implementation

            @Override
            public Type getRawType() {
                return pt.getRawType();
            }

            @Override
            public Type getOwnerType() {
                return pt.getOwnerType();
            }

            @Override
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("%s<%s>", getRawType().getTypeName(),
                    Arrays.stream(getActualTypeArguments())
                        .map(Type::getTypeName)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
            }
        };
    }
    return from;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Really didn't want to prepare that myself

Comment: @Jorn Vernee will it work with other type parameters?
I mean count of classes type parameters, w\wo extending , D<T> / T, different inheritance depth

Comment: @nitro-n It should work, because a `TypeVariable` object knows which class it belongs to. So type variables with the same name don't conflict. If you want to expand on what I've shown, all you should need to do is add more mappings to the map.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of @JornVernee idea.

*usage:*

```
getFieldsTypesMap(A)
```

*code:*

```
private static Map<Field, Type> getFieldsTypesMap(Class<?> aClass, Type[] actualTypeParameters) {
    Map<Field, Type> fieldTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
    TypeVariable<? extends Class<?>>[] typeParameters = aClass.getTypeParameters();

    Map<TypeVariable<?>, Type> mappings = new HashMap<>();

    if (typeParameters.length > 0 && actualTypeParameters != null) {
        mappings = IntStream.range(0, typeParameters.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> typeParameters[i], i -> actualTypeParameters[i]));
    }
    for (Field f : aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
            continue;
        }
        Type fieldType = getRealFieldType(f.getGenericType(), mappings);
        fieldTypeMap.put(f, fieldType);
    }

    Class<?> superclass = aClass.getSuperclass();
    Type genericSuperclass = aClass.getGenericSuperclass();
    if (genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        Type[] actual = ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass).getActualTypeArguments();
        Type[] remapped = new Type[actual.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
            remapped[i] = getRealFieldType(actual[i], mappings);
        }
        fieldTypeMap.putAll(getFieldsTypesMap(superclass, remapped));
    } else if (superclass != null) {
        fieldTypeMap.putAll(getFieldsTypesMap(superclass, null));
    }
    return fieldTypeMap;
}

private static Type getRealFieldType(Type from, Map<TypeVariable<?>, Type> mappings) {
    if(from instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) from;

        Type[] actualTypeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        Type[] result = new Type[actualTypeArguments.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < actualTypeArguments.length; i++) {
            result[i] = getRealFieldType(mappings.getOrDefault(actualTypeArguments[i], actualTypeArguments[i]), mappings);
        }

        return new ParameterizedType() {

            @Override
            public Type getRawType() {
                return parameterizedType.getRawType();
            }

            @Override
            public Type getOwnerType() {
                return parameterizedType.getOwnerType();
            }

            @Override
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("%s<%s>", getRawType().getTypeName(),
                        Arrays.stream(getActualTypeArguments())
                                .map(Type::getTypeName)
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
            }
        };
    }
    return mappings.getOrDefault(from, from);
}
```